# SilverLight ListBoxDragDropTarget not changing order

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm working with a ListBoxDragDropTarget and when I drag N drop an item, the ObservableCollection which is bind to the ListBox does not change its item order.

```
 <controlsToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"             
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                               Margin="0,10,8,10"
                                               ItemDragCompleted="ListBoxDragDropTarget_ItemDragCompleted_1"
                                               BorderThickness="0">
                  <ListBox x:Name="servicesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceCollection}" 
                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                           SelectionChanged="servicesListBox_SelectionChanged_1"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedService, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                           Margin="0,102,0,0" Background="#FF040404"
                           SelectionMode="Extended"
                           Foreground="White" Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF040404" Height="340" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <controlsToolkit:WrapPanel />
                          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Width="250" Margin="4" Orientation="Horizontal">                                    
                                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{Binding IsDesactivated, Converter={StaticResource OnlineColorConverter}}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0" Width="190" />
                            </StackPanel>
                          </DataTemplate>
                      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  </ListBox>
            </controlsToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your items in the ObservableCollection are heterogeneous. This happens when you use polymorphisme, for instance if your have an ObservableCollection but that it actually holds elements of type MyClass. This is a bug of the ListBoxDragDropTarget, but this control is in the "Experimental" quality band.

Two possible fixes:

- Use an ObservableCollection and make sure you have only
  instances of MyClass in it
- Use that fix:
  http://cjbhaines.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/silverlight-listboxdragdroptarget-why-cant-i-drop-it-there/